# Comparing two or more values in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, vertica, relational-division

I have a table which has the following.

```
 fieldmapid | fieldid
------------+---------
       2010 |     180
       2012 |      90
       2012 |      92
       2020 |      90
       2020 |      92
       2020 |      95
       20005 |      90
       20005 |      92
```

I want to write a query which first gets the fieldid's of the fieldmapid(assume it's 2012). And then i want to select the fieldmapid's which have the same fieldid's as the ones in 2012. That means, I need fieldmapid's which have only 90 and 92 as their fieldid's and nothing else. so i want 20005 and 2012 as the output of the query. because these are the only two fieldmapid's which have only 90 and 92 as their fieldid's.

Comment: Are you using Vertica or MySQL?

Comment: You need to provide the desired result set and what you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.May be it will help you.

```
select f.fieldmapid from Field f
LEFT JOIN Field f1 on f1.fieldid=f.fieldid and 

 (f1.fieldmapid=2012) 
group by f.fieldmapid
having 
count(f.fieldmapid)=count(f1.fieldmapid);
```

Demo link : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b72e05/3

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of a "set-within-sets" subquery.  You can solve it by doing:

```
select t.fieldmapids
from table t left outer join
     (select fieldid
      from table t2
      where fieldmapid = 2012
     ) f2012
     on f2012.fieldmapid = t.fieldmapid
group by t.fieldmapids
having count(*) = count(f2012.fieldmapid) and
       count(*) = (select count(*) from table t2 where fieldmapid = 2012);
```

The first condition in the `having` clause checks that all the fields for a given `fieldmapid` match at least one field for 2012.  The second verifies that the number of fields on `fieldmapid` matches the number on 2012.

Comment: Can this really not be simplified?